# Why is the time slow on my winforms stopwatch?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a small winforms program to be a small stopwatch program. My main problem is that the time gets updated slowly. 
For example, it takes approximately 3.5 seconds for my stopwatch program to pass 1 second and I am trying to figure out if there is a better way to handle the time?

I tried to include all of the relevant and only the relevant parts of code.

Global variables:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer microTimer;
EventHandler microTick;
AlertBox box;
string message;
Stopwatch watch;
```

Method to set Timer

```
private void SetTimer(int miliseconds)
    {
        microTimer.Interval = miliseconds;
        microTimer.Enabled = true;
        microTimer.Tick += microTick;
        microTimer.Start();
    }
```

The theory behind my event logic is for every tick on my timer, it checks the time on the Stopwatch and updates the label on my form with the elapsed time.

```
microTick = (m_sender, m_e) =>
            {
                TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(watch.ElapsedTicks);
                lblTimeDisplay.Text = t.Minutes + " : " + t.Seconds + " : " + t.Milliseconds;
            };
```

And here is my click event!

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetTimer(1); //I copied this earlier in the message.
        watch.Start();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you're calling an event that's updating a textbox 1000 times a second.

Comment: Do you know what a millisecond is?

Comment: Agreed, you are working it to death!  For the sake of ease, maybe specify the interval parameter as second and multiply by 1000 in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: it would be best to start the stopwatch just before you start the timer... not after...

2: in order to display the time properly on the form, you will need to run the timer's tick on a separate thread... running your timer at a 1 ms interval will loop so fast that it will lock the display thread and therefore the "UpdateDisplay" call in the back-end won't be able to fire fast enough to refresh the screen to accurately represent the values as they change... to confirm this, try SetTimer(1000)... then it will display accurately every 1 second...

to find out how to do this just lookup threading for C# in google.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic version of the code that runs as desired. I had to create the stopwatch inside of a new thread to make it run at a normal speed.

my usings:

```
using System.Threading;
```

main code:

global variables:

```
private new Thread starter;
private bool isThreadRunning = false;
```

Click events:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.isThreadRunning = true;
    //create new thread to run stopwatch in
    this.starter = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.HandleTime)); 
    this.starter.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cause the thread to end itself
    this.isThreadRunning = false;
}
```

Code that is run inside of thread

```
//HandleTime is inside the new thread
private void HandleTime()
{
    Stopwatch threadStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    TimeSpan timespan;
    threadStopwatch.Start();
    while (this.isThreadRunning)
    {
        timespan = threadStopwatch.Elapsed;
        //using invoke to update the label which is in the original thread 
        //and avoid a cross thread exception
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                //read up on lamda functions if you don't know what this is doing
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
                    label1.Text = timespan.Minutes + " : " + timespan.Seconds + " : " + timespan.Milliseconds
                    ));
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = timespan.Minutes + " : " + timespan.Seconds + " : " + timespan.Milliseconds;
            }
    }

}
```